# Tinymce repeats a Template when go new line in content

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

I'm using **Tinymce 5.9.1** with `template` plugin.

I made a new template like this code with special css code :

```
templates: [
     {title: 'green-box', description: 'box tiny green', content: '<div class="tiny-green-box"> Content </div><div class="p-1"></div></br>'},],
```

It works when edit content in one line. when i want to put multiple line there is a problem.

Tinymce duplicates template for every new line.

for example if i type line1 and press ENTER it will create new div and result will be something like this :

[image]

you can see in html code it repeates many time :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

putting content inside an extra `<p></p>` **tag** can solve this problem.
final code must be something like this :

```
templates: [
     {
title: 'green-box', 
description: 'box tiny green', 
content: '<div class="tiny-green-box"><p> Content </p></div><div class="p-1"></div></br>'
}
,],
```

The result HTML code will be like this :

```
<div class="tiny-green-box">
<p>line 1</p>
<p>line 2</p>
<p>line 3</p>
<p>line 4</p>
</div>
```